# Sharing Socks5 proxy over wifi

Tags: linux, dnsmasq, hotspot, hostapd, socks5

i have been trying to make a hotspot that get's it's traffic through a socks5 proxy to use that on my phone without having to install a socks5 client on the phone directly

First setup: i tried to setup squid+hostapd+dnsmasq in the same vm but seems like dnsmasq and hostapd services have a problem working together since dnsmasq tries to access the wireless card before hostapd and seems to not find it.

Second Setup: i tried making a seperate VM that handles the Proxifying and then routes the traffic to a seperate VM that has hostapd i managed the get the two machines to communicate but not to get the traffic routed could be something wrong on my IPTables config which ChatGPT has made.

i was wondering if there is a solution that already has what i need already setup on it otherwise any suggestions would be appreciated.